# Get url of images in firebase, with angularfire2

Tags: firebase, angular6, firebase-storage

I'm adding images to the firebase storage, using angularFire2, what I need now is to get those urls from the images to show them in a gallery so they can appear just after they load, I tried some things but I have not been successful, I hope you can help me, my code is as follows:

components.ts:

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireStorage, AngularFireUploadTask } from 'angularfire2/storage';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AngularFirestore } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { filter, switchMap } from '../../../../node_modules/rxjs/operators';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';





@Component({
  selector: 'app-file-upload',
  templateUrl: './file-upload.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./file-upload.component.scss']
})
export class FileUploadComponent implements OnInit {

  urlImages: string

  // Main task 
  task: AngularFireUploadTask;

  // Progress monitoring
  percentage: Observable<number>;

  snapshot: Observable<any>;

  // Download URL
  downloadURL: Observable<string>;

  // State for dropzone CSS toggling
  isHovering: boolean;
  //variable para obtener url
  image: string

  constructor(private storage: AngularFireStorage, private db: AngularFirestore) { }


  ngOnInit() {
  }



  toggleHover(event: boolean) {
    this.isHovering = event;
  }


  startUpload(event: FileList) {
    // The File object
    const file = event.item(0)

    // Client-side validation example
    if (file.type.split('/')[0] !== 'image') {
      console.error('unsupported file type :( ')
      return;
    }

    // El path del archivo en storage
    const path = `blog/${new Date().getTime()}_${file.name}`;

    // Metadata Personalizada
    const customMetadata = { app: 'CMS DsnAdmin' };

    // Declaramos la tarea
    this.task = this.storage.upload(path, file, { customMetadata })

    // Porcentaje de Carga
    this.percentage = this.task.percentageChanges();
    console.log('Image cargada!');
    this.snapshot = this.task.snapshotChanges()

    // Url del archivo
    const task = this.storage.upload(path, file);
    const ref = this.storage.ref(path);

  }

  // Determines if the upload task is active
  isActive(snapshot) {
    return snapshot.state === 'running' && snapshot.bytesTransferred < snapshot.totalBytes
  }

}
```

I hope you can help me I am very new in this network, in case you ask the question in some incorrect way.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the defined property to hold the download URL

```
downloadURL: Observable<string>;
```

by using `finalize()` on the `task.snapshotChanges()`, and you can get the downloadURL from the `ref` object.

```
// get notified when the download URL is available
task.snapshotChanges().pipe(
    finalize(() => this.downloadURL = ref.getDownloadURL() )
 )
.subscribe()
```

Please check more at: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/storage/storage.md

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo me funcionó.